# How do I perform Facebook authentication in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, authentication, koala

I've been struggling through Facebook authentication for a canvas app for a while. My approach is as follows:

1. Check the user's session for an access token.
2. Check the user's Facebook cookies for an access token.
3. Check the parameters for a `signed_request`.

If an access token is found during any of those 3 steps:

- I make a call to the graph API requesting the `/me` resource.

  - If the call is successful, the user is logged in.
  - If the call fails (causes an `OAuthException`), I request a new access token by redirecting the user to the Facebook OAuth endpoint to obtain a code, then obtaining a fresh access token by exchanging that code.

If no access token is found in the session, cookies, or `signed_request`, I display a landing page.

**Is this the correct procedure?** I've noticed that oftentimes there is no `signed_request` present in the parameters if the user's access token has expired. The method Facebook endorses for requesting a fresh access token results in 2 user-facing redirects as well as an API exchange, which seems a bit heavy.

The setup I'm working in is:

- Rails v3.0.8
- Koala gem v1.2.1

I've followed these guides:

- https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth
- https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using Omniauth? (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) It wraps up all this stuff and lets you easily extend to other sites as well.

Comment: +1 for this. Use the 'omniauth' and 'omniauth-facebook' gems, configure your app credentials and you're done. No really, you're done.

Comment: I'll try to authenticate using Omniauth and see if I can get it to work.